# auto parallelization unsafe calls

Tags: c, parallel-processing, solaris

I have ran into a problem when I was playing around with the auto parallelization function of the Oracle Solaris Compiler. Let's say I have the following code:

```
int var = -1;
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
  bool flag = false;
  // do operations to set the flag
  if (flag == true)
    var = i;
}
// do other operations with var
```

when I run this code, the compiler complains that it cannot be parallelized because of unsafe dependences.

Does anyone know what might be wrong here? Is there any way to avoid this but maintain the original functionality of the code?

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: I haven't worked with this compiler, but you can try `#pragma MP taskloop storeback (var)` before for loop

Comment: It's very unlikely that the if branch has caused the dependency. I guess there are more dependency across loops that prevents next loop to start before current one finishes. Usually it's pointer aliasing, try adding restrict keywords to your pointers where safe.

Answer (score 0):

What the compiler sees is a bunch of loop iterations, all of which can potentially assign to V.   If writing to V *happens* to be atomic, then this will get some random value of i, and one might argue that is OK.  Under the assumption that writing to a variable is not atomic, most compilers see this as a data race ... (then what exactly ends up in V?).   Thus the complaint.